# Jquery - find window width and put it in a hidden field

Tags: jquery, forms, window

Is it possible to find out the window width of the browser and then put it as a value in a hidden field?

Thank you in advance.

Update: I know I should be familiar with jQuery - is this how I use the code?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" >/script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var MyWindowwidth = $(window).width();
        $("#thew").val(MyWindowwidth);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="">
        <input type="hidden" id="thew" name="thew" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="subm" id="subm" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Any code to show us? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: yes! this is how you will use the code.$(function(){var MyWindowwidth = $(window).width();  $("#thew").val(MyWindowwidth);});

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#yourHiddenFieldId").val($(window).width());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyWindowwidth = $(window).width();     // get Width 
$("#idOfMyHiddenField").val(MyWindowwidth); // Put width in your Hidden field with id :idOfMyHiddenField
```